# Какими средствами можно отловить момент освобождения объекта?

Tags: delphi, утечка-памяти

Имеется массив объектов. В определённый момент программы из него пропадает один из элементов... Всегда один и тот же и в том же месте программы, которая с ним никак не связана и никаким образом не имеет на него влияния.

Выглядит всё так, будто именно этот объект был когда-то освобождён и теперь память занимаемая им ранее, заполняется под другие нужды. (Хотя это всё равно странно, т.к. это кусочек в 48 байт в середине огромного массива... почему именно он? если кому-то понадобилась память, зачем её выдялять в середине массива?) Хотя в деструктор этого объекта в отладчике я никогда не попадаю.

Убил несколько дней на поиски, но ни к чему не пришёл. Может есть какие-то штатные или сторонние средства, позволяющие выявить в какой момент освобождается определённая память или под что она в данный момент выделена?

Comment: Отладчиком ловится на ура =)

Comment: точнее пожалуйста, буду только счастлив поймать отладчиком)

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/post500631.html

Comment: На изменение переменной я знаю, но это мало помогает... ибо она изменяется, как я и писал выше, независимым кодом. точку изменения я знаю, но она никак не связана с проблеммой. Найти нужно когда и каким образом объект был освобождён/как-то испорчен(без деструктора). А в момент освобождения изменений самого объекта не происходит

Comment: Чтож вы все в дебри лезите то не понимая основ... чтобы освободить память - надо ее изменить, ставьте бряку на изменение массива(если элемент исчезает из массива(не элементов массива, а именно массива)) и ячейки которая вам нужна, и смотрите содержимое... у вас 2 варианта ошибки или кто то меняет массив(стирает ссылку на элемент при этом надо переформировать весь массив), либо кто то затирает "живые данные" своим "мусором"

Comment: p.s. чтобы использовать "память" объекта нет необходимости ее освобождать, можно просто дублировать ссылку на этот кусок памяти, и у вас скорее всего именно этот случай, не балуйтесь адресной математикой не понимая что там происходит....

Comment: наверняка! но разбираться то когда-то надо начинать... я пока не понимал абсолютно, вообще долго не мог добиться рабочего состояния, теперь вроде всё(кроме этого момента) работает. ссылки да там дублируются, в процессе заполнения массива у меня есть несколько ссылок на позиции, которые гуляют по массиву в поисках места для вставки. Их нужно уконце как-то уничтожить чтоли?

Comment: Нет, их уничтожать не нужно, нужно следить за тем что они делают =) ибо с их помощью ой как легко "портить" данные даже валидными с вашей точки зрения действиями =)

Comment: Дважды прочитал вопрос и комментарии. Что-то так и не понял, что требуется ТСу и в чем именно его проблема.

Comment: Его проблема в том что в момент работы программы по одному адрессу из массива адресов(ссылок на обьекты) появляется мусор вместо обьекта или ссылка на мусор вместо нормальной... и он не может найти какой код творит непотребства в памяти

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков спасибо, теперь все понял! Дебаггер и `nil` наше все.

Comment: @Dima, да не совсем всё, на nil я проверял, он не nil. Указывает на правильную часть памяти... только память заполняется мусором, потому заранее проверить на проблеммный элемент тоже не просто, только по исключению при попытке доступа понимаешь

Comment: Нет, я про `nil` совсем другое имел в виду. Если объект не нужен и ссылок на него нет, то нужно освободить занимаемую им память, и установить ссылку на объект равную `nil`. Что-то вроде (пример): `MyArray[1].Free; MyArray[1] := nil;`. `MyArray` это массив объектов, естественно. Тогда никаких проблем с доступом. Есть объект - `Assigned(obj)` вернет `true`; нет объекта - вернет `false`.

Comment: это то ясно.... я их не освобождаю, только создаю. освобождает их класс, когда закончит свою работу (естественно уже после возникновения проблеммы). Но я примерно понял проблему, благодаря объяснениям Владимира, дома попробую ещё раз разобраться в причине

Comment: Очень похоже на утечку памяти. В смысле где-то идет запись в чужой адрес. FastMM вам в помощь: https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4

Comment: А тот FastMM, что встроен в Delphi сильно отличается? Они же вроде их купили.

Comment: Как это я пропустил такой интересный вопрос :)? Покажите хоть немного кода.

Answer (score 2):

Начать стоит с [подключения](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/) модуля контроля памяти *FastMM*.

Причем в "тяжелом" режиме, т.е. не только включить его в `dpr`, но и задействовать `FullDebugMode` в файле `FastMM4Options.inc`.

Повреждения объекта хорошо ловятся точкой остановки нестандартного типа - по адресу памяти, которая ставится заведомо до повреждения на одной из его переменных.

Т.е. нужно запустить программу, остановиться уже после создания объекта и посмотреть адрес чего-либо в нем (`$MyClass.Name` или через `Watch`).
Затем поставить на этот адрес `Address Breakpoint` или `Data Breakpoint`. При правильной постановке они остановятся при любых изменениях значения по адресу.

Также нужно по-возможности использовать `FreeAndNil` вместо `Free` и прочих способов освобождения объектов.

Comment: На счёт "тяжёлого" режима надо посмотреть. Я вообще думал, что с момента включения fastmm в Delphi в его отдельном подключении смысл пропал. На счёт брекпоинтов, проблема как раз в том, что при освобождении память не обнуляется и в отладчике видишь значение, когда ссылка на него уже убита... И оно вроде как есть есть, а при обращении бац и ошибка доступа. Оказывается оно уже давно не существует, хотя значение в памяти ещё видно... В общем то в этом и была проблема.

Comment: @Isaev Память не освобождается. Какой-то другой код залезает в нее и записывает туда что-то, после чего объект, который находился в этом месте становится испорченным. Поэтому и нужен breakpoint, выстреливающий на запись по адресу.

Comment: @Igor, так он выстрелит когда/если кто-то захочет это место (размеченное, как свободное, но не обнулённое) использовать и это не помогает отловить момент когда оно освободилось

Comment: @Isaev Из Вашего описания следует, что оно *не освободилось*, но какой-то код туда залез и что-то записал. Этот код надо найти.

Comment: Точка остановки по адресу памяти имеет тип, к примеру, для char отладчик будет мониторить 1 байт, для wchar - 2 байта. Насколько помню, там есть возможность поставить свое значение, т.е. если задать ей размер 48, то можно гарантировать целостность объекта и отлов неисправности.

Comment: @AnnoNymous Чтобы "испортить" объект, не обязательно затирать все место, которое он занимает. Но автор почему-то не хочет говорить, что у него за "объекты".

Comment: Точка остановки отреагирует на любое изменение в рамках этих 48 байт. Насколько понимаю, именно в этом была задача.

Comment: @Igor, из моего описания следует, что я создал объект, а его кто-то убил. Данные в памяти от него остались, т.к. при Free они не очищаются, а при попытке обращения, естественно ловим исключение. Найти надо кто и когда его убивает

Comment: @Isaev "Хотя в деструктор этого объекта в отладчике я никогда не попадаю." - Это фраза прямо кричит о том, что никто объект не "убивал", а переписано место в памяти, где он был.

Comment: @Igor, твоя правда, больше года прошло, запамятовал